# Слияние массивов PHP

Tags: php, массивы, песочница

Здравствуйте, есть ли возможность объединить массивы?

```
$array[]= [1,2,3,4];
$array1[]= [5,6,7,8];
$array2[]= //на выходе должно получится [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, можно. С помощью [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php):

```
$array2 = array_merge($array, $array1);
```

Если ключи числовые (как тут, просто в неявном виде), в результирующем массиве будут все значения.

Comment: думаю стоит написать и про `$first_array += $second_array`, иногда `+` полезнее тупого мерджа